# How can I update PyQt5 WebEngineView?

Tags: pyqt5

How can I update Chrome in Pyqt5 QWebEngineView? Whatsapp works on Chrome version 60+.

[image: Pictures]

Comment: the google search "error whatsapp works with chrome 60+" gives me 50k websites. First entry has 5 ways to solve the problem.

Comment: @accpert.com None of those links will help, though, because [the version of Chrome used by WebEngine](https://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngine/ChromiumVersions) is tied to the Qt version. But even if the latest version of Qt is used, there's no guarantee that a given website will explicitly support WebEngine-based browsers. It may sometimes be necessary to spoof the user-agent. (And even then, it's always possible that some websites have buggy user-agent parsing).

Comment: To debug this, it would help if you created a simple test script that loads the whatapp url, and add something like `print(webView.page().profile().httpUserAgent())`. Then update your question with the output from that. You could also try copying the user-agent of a browser that works with whatsapp, and then setting that in your test script (i.e. `webView.page().profile().setHttpUserAgent(working_ua_string)`).